# access SOAPHeader in java webservice code (not via a handler)

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I need to access the SOAPHeader in my webservice code (i need it to generate some objects from the security-part of the header using an external library).

It works fine in a SOAPHandler, but if i try the following in the actual webservice method i get an exception.

```
SOAPMessageContext soapMsgContext = (SOAPMessageContext) webServiceContext.getMessageContext();
SOAPHeader soapHeader =  soapMsgContext.getMessage().getSOAPHeader();
```

Exception:

```
JAXBBlockImpl block object is already consumed. Processing cannot continue.
```

I would like to do one of the following:

1. Process the header in the handler and get the resulting object to the webservice method.
2. Process the header in the webservice method.

Can anyone tell me how to do either one of these steps?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, not sure if this is a pretty solution, so i leave the question open for now.

In the SOAPHandler i put the object in the servlet request like so:

```
servletRequest.setAttribute("param-name", myObject);
```

and in the webservice method i retrieve it like so:

```
MessageContext messageContext = webServiceContext.getMessageContext();
HttpServletRequest servletRequest = HttpServletRequest)messageContext.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
myObject = (myObject) servletRequest.getAttribute("param-name");
```